# Why is skype message count orange rather than red

Tags: skype

Whenever a skype message is received a message count appears on the taskbar item, and a red number appears against the person who sent the message

For the last few days when one person sends me a message there is no number placed on the task bar icon, and the count against their name is orange. I don't see that a message has been received without manually bringing skype to the front.

Why might this be happening? The person is online, and has logged out and in again several times

**Update:**

Things work as expected using a different skype account to send the message, so it must be account related, but what could it be?

Comment: Did Skype auto-update recently, by any chance?

Comment: @lzam Quite possibly

Comment: Has your (or the recipient's) status changed? Skype -> Online Status. You mention `the person` is online, have you tried with any other contacts?